# Смена дня и ночи, или Почему ночь у меня темная, а источник освещения не такой темный?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю смену дня и ночи на юнити. День и ночь сменяются, но когда идет ночь, все очень темно, хотя я поставил цвет не черный. Как сделать так чтобы оно не было настолько темно?

Скриншот:

[image: день]
[image: Ночь]

Код скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DayNightChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Gradient directLight;
    [SerializeField] Gradient ambLight;

    const float timeDayInSeconds = 60f;
        
    [SerializeField, Range(0f, 1f)] float timeProgress;

    [SerializeField] Light lightSource;

    Vector3 defaultAngles;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        defaultAngles = lightSource.transform.localEulerAngles;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Application.isPlaying) timeProgress += Time.deltaTime / timeDayInSeconds;

        if (timeProgress > 1f) timeProgress = 0f;

        lightSource.color = directLight.Evaluate(timeProgress);
        RenderSettings.ambientLight = ambLight.Evaluate(timeProgress);

        lightSource.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(360f * timeProgress - 90, 
defaultAngles.x, defaultAngles.z);
    }
}
```

Comment: тот человек, который поставил минус, можешь объяснить пожалуйста, что тебе не хватает? я с радостью изменю вопрос так как тебе надо

Comment: Чтобы не было настолько темно, вам нужны источники света - луна и звезды. :)

Comment: @alex9127 Не волнуйся, минусы ставят часто, не объясняя за что. Просто смирись:) Обращай внимание на плюсы и на помогающих тебе людей. Получается вы разворачиваете ваш источник освещения в противоположную сторону? Поэтому и тьма.  Либо не разворачивайте его так сильно, либо, правда, добавьте луну с меньшей интенсивностью света. Светить-то что-то должно

Comment: @МаксимФисман то есть мне нужен второй directionalLight?

Comment: @МаксимФисман спасибо вам, вы мне помогли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался. Если у вас такая же проблема в таком же коде (примерно), просто добавьте второй DirectionalLight и сделайте ему такой же скрипт только измените `- 90` на `- 270` в последней строке `Update()` и измените градиенты так чтобы они соответствовали ночному свету.

Comment: А как насчет не поворачивать источники освещения, а с наступлением вечера уменьшать интенсивность (intensity) дневного света до нуля и параллельно ночного до 1, а днем наоборот? Просто порекомендовал. Как делать, решать, естественно вам. Какой вариант будет выглядть натуральнее - точно не могу сказать

Comment: я нихрена не знаю в юнити, поэтому мне пришлось делать все по туториалу. я выбрал самый понятный и скопировал его) потом дополнил, у меня все получилось

Comment: Чтож, круто. Однако советую не копировать, а писать или хотя бы переписывать код самому, ВДУМЫВАЯСЬ. Всречается незнакомая функция - посмотреть. Возможно не все запомнится, по копировать код не до конца понимая его - это плохо. Ладно, поздравляю, что решили проблему... Удачи:)

Comment: спасибо, я уже сделал еще и смену погоды) причем наполовину сам)